# Redis on windows with HTTP interface and JSON as output

Tags: caching, redis

I'm looking to run redis on windows, so I found this famous GitHub repository:
https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Redis

My problem is that I also need to expose it with an HTTP interface, which outputs JSON.
So I found that repository:
https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis
but apparently it works only on Linux and Mac.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

There is also https://github.com/markuman/tinywebdis 
The only dependency is a C compiler (e.g. TCC) and lua. Because both is available on windows, it should be runnable.

*PS: Nor I've tried tinywebdis on Windows nor I'm a Windows user.*

**UPDATE**

There are now two versions of tinywebdis.
1) tinywebdis (branch tinywebdis) - depends only on Lua and needs a C compiler.
2) turbowebdis (master branch) - depends on luajit (dependencies can be installed with luarocks).

*PS: I am the author*